# Who can help me with a Regular Expression check?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and want to check if the string contains a partial string.
Example:
Check if string contains: "PA" OR "PB" OR "POL" OR "VBW"

> String1 to check: "COR,PA,NOT,VBW" --> Check = True
>
> String2 to check: "COR,PB,NOT,VW-PBM-BR-INVE-INV6" --> Check = True
>
> String3 to check: "COR,VW-PBM-BR-INVE-INV6" --> Check = False

I have used Regex `(PA)|(PB)|(POL)|(VBW)`
String1 and String2 have a right check
But String3 also give Check = True

The partial String "PA" OR "PB" OR "POL" OR "VBW" is always between a (,) Comma, at the begin of the string, at the end of the string or the whole string.
The Partial String is never in a combination like "VW-PBM-BR-INVE-INV6" or "POLIS"

Comment: That seems to work just [**fine**](https://regex101.com/r/QI5Ks1/1), can you show your code, did you check the groups, that is what you need to look at as you are capturing groups.

Comment: Are you wanting to make sure there's a comma at the beginning and or end, I may be miss-understanding this.

Comment: `(?<=,)(PA|PB|POL|VBW)|(PA|PB|POL|VBW)(?=,)` that could work if you want to check for `,` either before and or after what you are looking for.

Comment: thnx @Çöđěxěŕ for your answer, but the code didn't work. No problem cause the other answers help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.

```
"(^|,)(PA|PB|POL|VBW)(,|$)"
```

It checks for start of string or comma before your required strings & also end of string or comma following them.

This means you third example will return false as PB is preceded by - & followed by M - so no match.

See here - https://regex101.com/r/QI5Ks1/2

From the original question I assumed all you needed was true/false check if any substring matched your groups - if you want to capture all matching groups of your substrings - you can use lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

```
((?<=^)|(?<=,))(PA|PB|POL|VBW)((?=$)|(?=,))
```

See here - https://regex101.com/r/QI5Ks1/5

Comment: thnx @PaulF for your answer. This code is fine for me. Only if two partial Strings in a row `POL,PB,PA` then the second part get's a false check. But that's no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try your regex with word boundaries anchor:

```
(PA|PB|POL|VBW)\b
```

Comment: Probably need a word boundary and **both** start and end of the string.

Comment: Thnx for your answers. This code is ok for me. Only when I have a string like this `M-PB-HOME` then the check will also true.